# Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for bash: * libc * in openwrt

Tags: bash, openwrt

My router is wndr3800ch ,os is CHAOS CALMER (15.05.1, r48532).

```
opkg install bash
Installing bash (4.3.39-1) to root...
Downloading http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/packages/bash_4.3.39-1_ar71xx.ipk.
 Collected errors:
 * satisfy_dependencies_for: Cannot satisfy the following dependencies for bash:
 *  libc *  libc *  libc * 
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package bash.
```

How to fix the libc * problem ?

```
root@OpenWrt:~# opkg install libc
Unknown package 'libc'.
Collected errors:
* opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libc.
```

Answer (score 3):

libc is located at https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/libc_0.9.33.2-1_ar71xx.ipk

To install it this way.

```
opkg install https://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05.1/ar71xx/generic/packages/base/libc_0.9.33.2-1_ar71xx.ipk
```

Comment: In the 19.07.7  release the libc package is missing. You can try Ctrl+F here https://downloads.openwrt.org/releases/19.07.7/packages/mips_24kc/base/

Comment: At the same time all packages still have a dependency to the libc in their control file. And I do see the /lib/libc.so (and  ld-musl-mips-sf.so.1). I tried to install program with ignoring dependency problems and it worked. Not sure how to tell opkg that I already have the libc